how to add different layer options
I have a samll script that allows you to add a "shades" layer to any uploaded image and then save it. Currently you can only add one style of shades. I need help figuring out how to add different shade options to the script. it's suppose to work when the user clicks the shades they want. Also would like to have the option to flip the shades.
i've got it partially working by duplicating the script for each shade. i have 4-5 different shades.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Choose your FOMO Shades</h1>
    
  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.3.1/konva.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>FOMO Shades</title>

          <style>
            .russo-one-regular {
              font-family: "saira", sans-serif;
              font-weight: 400;
              font-style: normal;
              }
            
            body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center;
              flex-direction: column; /* NEW ADD */
              background-color: #2F2E2E;
              min-height: 80vh;
              font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif; /* Use your custom font here */
            }

            /* #container-wrapper {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center;
            } */

            #container-wrapper {
              position: relative;
            }

            #canvas-container {
              position: relative;
              background-color: transparent;
              /* margin: auto; */ /* NEW ADD */
            }

            #uploadButton,
            #saveButton {
              letter-spacing: 2px;
              font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif; /* Use your custom font here */
              margin: 10px;
              cursor: pointer;
              color: #ffff;
              background-color: #ff9100;
              font-size: 18px;
              border: 2px solid #fff;
              padding: 10px;
              border-radius: 0;
              transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
              font-weight: 600px;
            }
            
           
             #flipButton {
              letter-spacing: 2px;
              font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif; /* Use your custom font here */
              margin: 10px;
              cursor: pointer;
              color: #ffff;
              background-color: #ff9100;
              font-size: 10px;
              border: 2px solid #fff;
              padding: 5px;
              border-radius: 0;
              transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
              font-weight: 600px;
            }
            
            #flipButton:hover {
              background-color: #d17700;
              color: white;
            }

            #uploadButton:hover,
            #saveButton:hover {
              background-color: #d17700;
              color: white;
            }

            #saveButton {
              display: none; /* Initially hide the save button */
            }

            #closeButton {
              /* NEW ADD */
              opacity: 0.5;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-size: 18px;
              border: 2px solid #fff;
              border-radius: 50%;
              transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out,
                color 0.3s ease-in-out;
              position: absolute;
              top: 10px;
              right: 10px;
              color: #ffff;
              background-color: #333;
              width: 40px; /* Set width and height to make it circular */
              height: 40px;
              text-align: center;
            }

            #closeButton:hover {
              /* NEW ADD */
              background-color: #ff9100;
              opacity: 1;
              color: white;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
              #container-wrapper {
                width: 100%; /* Full width of its parent */
              }
              #canvas-container {
                width: 100%; /* Take full width to utilize the space */
                max-width: 300px; /* But don't grow beyond 300px */
                max-height: 300px; /* Same for height */
                margin: auto; /* Center horizontally */
                overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
                display: flex; /* Use flexbox to center content */
                justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
                align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
              }
              .konvajs-content {
                width: 100%; /* Let it fill the container */
                max-width: 250px; /* But don't exceed 250px */
                height: auto; /* Adjust height automatically */
                position: relative;
                user-select: none;
              }
              .konvajs-content canvas {
                width: 100% !important; /* Override inline styles for responsiveness */
                height: auto !important; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
                max-width: 250px; /* Respect the max-width of .konvajs-content */
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
              }
            }
            #fomo-title {
              font-size: 50px;
              margin: 0;
            }
            #fomo-subheading {
              font-size: 15px;
              margin: 0;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              font-family: helvetica;
              font-weight: 200;
            }
            #fomo-header {
              color: #fff;
            }

        #button1{
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        appearance: none;
        background-color: inherit;
         transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
        margin-left:10px;

      }
      #button1:hover{
        transform: rotate(10deg);

      }
        #button2{
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        appearance: none;
        background-color: inherit;
         transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
        margin-left:10px;

      }
      #button2:hover{
        transform: rotate(10deg);
      }
  
      img{
        width: 110px;
        height: 50px;
      }
      
          </style>
        
       <div class="text">
       
          <button id="button1">
             <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/16c0c5_3fe6bfe914f24f0ca06ad57e8d80a77b~mv2.png" alt="buttonpng" border="0" />
          </button>
          
          <button id="button2">
             <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/16c0c5_85ea6942ee63447ba548a3e3b9b090f4~mv2.png" alt="buttonpng" border="0" />
          </button>
          
          </div>
        
          <div id="flip">
          
          <button id="flipButton">flip Image</button>
          
          </div>
        
          <div style="text-align: center">
         
            <h2 style="color: #fff" id="fomo-subheading">
              Upload a picture to add FOMO shades
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div id="container-wrapper">
            <div id="canvas-container"><div class="konvajs-content" role="presentation" style="position: relative; user-select: none; width: 450px; height: 450px;"><canvas width="450" height="450" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; background: transparent; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 450px; height: 450px; display: block;"></canvas></div></div>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center">
              <button id="uploadButton">Upload Picture</button>
              <button id="saveButton" style="display: none;">Save Image</button>
            </div>
            <button id="closeButton" style="display: none;">✖</button>
          </div>

          <script>
            let fixedCanvasWidth, maxCanvasHeight;

            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
              // 768px is a common breakpoint for mobile devices
              fixedCanvasWidth = 250;
              maxCanvasHeight = 250;
            } else {
              fixedCanvasWidth = 450;
              maxCanvasHeight = 450;
            }

            const stage = new Konva.Stage({
              container: "canvas-container",
              width: fixedCanvasWidth,
              height: maxCanvasHeight,
            });

            const layer = new Konva.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);

            let shades;
            let shades2;
            let canvasBorder;
            let tr;

            const addShadesToCanvas = () => {
              const imgSrc =
                "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/16c0c5_3fe6bfe914f24f0ca06ad57e8d80a77b~mv2.png";
              
              canvasBorder = new Konva.Rect({
                width: stage.width(),
                height: stage.height(),
                stroke: "white",
                strokeWidth: 10,
              });
              

              layer.add(canvasBorder);      
              
               Konva.Image.fromURL(imgSrc, (img) => {
                shades = img;


                const aspectRatio = img.width() / img.height();             
             
                let newShadesWidth, newShadesHeight;

                if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                  // Mobile devices
                  newShadesWidth = 100;
                  newShadesHeight = 100 / aspectRatio;
                } else {
                  // Desktop
                  newShadesWidth = 250;
                  newShadesHeight = 250 / aspectRatio;
                }

                if (newShadesHeight > maxCanvasHeight) {
                  newShadesHeight = maxCanvasHeight;
                  newShadesWidth = maxCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
                }

                shades.setAttrs({
                  width: newShadesWidth,
                  height: newShadesHeight,
                  x: (stage.width() - newShadesWidth) / 2,
                  y: (stage.height() - newShadesHeight) / 2,
                  name: "shades",
                  draggable: true,
                });

                tr = new Konva.Transformer({
                  nodes: [shades],
                  enabledAnchors: [
                    "top-left",
                    "top-right",
                    "bottom-left",
                    "bottom-right",
                  ],
                  keepRatio: true,
                  boundBoxFunc: (oldBox, newBox) => {
                    if (
                      Math.abs(newBox.width) < 10 ||
                      Math.abs(newBox.height) < 10
                    ) {
                      return oldBox;
                    }
                    return newBox;
                  },

                  padding: 10,
                  rotateEnabled: true /* NEW ADD */,
                });

                shades.on("click tap", () => {
                  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                    // Mobile devices
                    tr.visible(!tr.visible());
                    layer.batchDraw();
                  } else {
                    // Desktop
                    tr.visible(!tr.visible());
                    layer.batchDraw();
                  }
                });

                layer.add(canvasBorder);
                layer.add(shades);
                layer.add(tr);
                tr.visible(false);

                // $("#saveButton").show();

                layer.batchDraw();
              });
            };
            

//=============================================

const addShadesToCanvas2 = () => {
              const imgSrc2 =
                "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/16c0c5_85ea6942ee63447ba548a3e3b9b090f4~mv2.png";
              
              canvasBorder = new Konva.Rect({
                width: stage.width(),
                height: stage.height(),
                stroke: "white",
                strokeWidth: 10,
              });
              

              layer.add(canvasBorder);      
              
               Konva.Image.fromURL(imgSrc2, (img) => {
                shades2 = img;
                const aspectRatio = img.width() / img.height();
                
                let newShadesWidth, newShadesHeight;

                if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                  // Mobile devices
                  newShadesWidth = 100;
                  newShadesHeight = 100 / aspectRatio;
                } else {
                  // Desktop
                  newShadesWidth = 250;
                  newShadesHeight = 250 / aspectRatio;
                }

                if (newShadesHeight > maxCanvasHeight) {
                  newShadesHeight = maxCanvasHeight;
                  newShadesWidth = maxCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
                }

                shades2.setAttrs({
                  width: newShadesWidth,
                  height: newShadesHeight,
                  x: (stage.width() - newShadesWidth) / 2,
                  y: (stage.height() - newShadesHeight) / 2,
                  name: "shades",
                  draggable: true,
                });

                tr = new Konva.Transformer({
                  nodes: [shades],
                  enabledAnchors: [
                    "top-left",
                    "top-right",
                    "bottom-left",
                    "bottom-right",
                  ],
                  keepRatio: true,
                  boundBoxFunc: (oldBox, newBox) => {
                    if (
                      Math.abs(newBox.width) < 10 ||
                      Math.abs(newBox.height) < 10
                    ) {
                      return oldBox;
                    }
                    return newBox;
                  },

                  padding: 10,
                  rotateEnabled: true /* NEW ADD */,
                });

                shades2.on("click tap", () => {
                  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                    // Mobile devices
                    tr.visible(!tr.visible());
                    layer.batchDraw();
                  } else {
                    // Desktop
                    tr.visible(!tr.visible());
                    layer.batchDraw();
                  }
                });

                layer.add(canvasBorder);
                layer.add(shades2);
                layer.add(tr);
                tr.visible(false);

                // $("#saveButton").show();

                layer.batchDraw();
              });
            };

//================================================



            const changeCanvasBackground = (imageSrc) => {
              const background = new Image();
              background.onload = function () {
                const aspectRatio = background.width / background.height;

                let newCanvasWidth = fixedCanvasWidth;
                let newCanvasHeight = fixedCanvasWidth / aspectRatio;

                if (newCanvasHeight > maxCanvasHeight) {
                  newCanvasHeight = maxCanvasHeight;
                  newCanvasWidth = maxCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
                }

                stage.width(newCanvasWidth);
                stage.height(newCanvasHeight);

                canvasBorder.width(newCanvasWidth);
                canvasBorder.height(newCanvasHeight);

                const bg = new Konva.Image({
                  image: background,
                  width: newCanvasWidth,
                  height: newCanvasHeight,
                });

                layer.destroyChildren();
                layer.add(bg);
                addShadesToCanvas();
                layer.batchDraw();
                $("#uploadButton").hide();
                $("#closeButton").show();
                $("#saveButton").show();
              };
              background.src = imageSrc;
            };

            const saveCanvasAsImage = () => {
              tr.visible(false);
              layer.batchDraw();

              const dataURL = stage.toDataURL({
                mimeType: "image/png",
                quality: 1,
                pixelRatio: 3,
              });
              const a = document.createElement("a");
              a.href = dataURL;
              a.download = "FOMO_shades.png";
              document.body.appendChild(a);
              a.click();
              document.body.removeChild(a);

              tr.visible(true);
              layer.batchDraw();
            };

            const resetCanvas = () => {
              $("#uploadButton").show();
              addShadesToCanvas();
              $("#closeButton").hide();
              $("#saveButton").hide();
              layer.destroyChildren();
              stage.width(fixedCanvasWidth);
              stage.height(maxCanvasHeight);
              canvasBorder = new Konva.Rect({
                width: stage.width(),
                height: stage.height(),
                stroke: "white",
                strokeWidth: 10,
              });
              layer.add(canvasBorder);
              layer.batchDraw();
            };
            
            const resetCanvas2 = () => {
              $("#uploadButton").show();
              addShadesToCanvas2();
              $("#closeButton").hide();
              $("#saveButton").hide();
              layer.destroyChildren();
              stage.width(fixedCanvasWidth);
              stage.height(maxCanvasHeight);
              canvasBorder = new Konva.Rect({
                width: stage.width(),
                height: stage.height(),
                stroke: "white",
                strokeWidth: 10,
              });
              layer.add(canvasBorder);
              layer.batchDraw();
            };

            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#closeButton").hide();
              $("#saveButton").hide();
              addShadesToCanvas();
            });

            $("#uploadButton").click(function () {
              const input = document.createElement("input");
              input.type = "file";
              input.accept = "image/*";

              input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
                const file = event.target.files[0];
                if (file) {
                  const reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function (event) {
                    const imageSrc = event.target.result;
                    changeCanvasBackground(imageSrc);
                  };
                  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
              });

              input.click();
            });

            $("#saveButton").click(function () {
              saveCanvasAsImage();
            });

            $("#closeButton").click(function () {
              resetCanvas();
            });

            // $("#saveButton").hide(); /* NEW ADD */

            // addMustacheToCanvas(); /* NEW ADD */
            
            
   $("#button2").click(function () {
  
          resetCanvas2();
         
    }); 
    
       $("#button1").click(function () {
  
          resetCanvas();
         
    });
            
          </script>
              

  </body>
</html>

